# pyTelegramBotAPI(telebot) exit from while by /stop command

Tags: python, while-loop, py-telegram-bot-api

I wrote a bot for checking the load avarage over snmp with the command: snmpwalk -v3 -l authNoPriv -u admin -a SHA -A "admin" ' + server + ' .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.1.

And I Can't exit the while loop by the stop command.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxxxx')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Please input server (example 192.168.0.1)')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, cores)

def cores(message):
    global server
    server = (message.text)
    sent2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Input number of cores')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent2, botstarted)

def botstarted(message):
    global core
    global bye
    core = (message.text)
    cores = float(core)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Check started, if load average more then number of cores you get Warning message to stop enter /stop')
    while (True):
        b = os.popen('snmpwalk -v3 -l authNoPriv -u admin -a SHA -A "admin" ' + server + ' .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.1').read()
        d = (b[39:43])
        c = float(b[39:43])
        if c > cores:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Warning, huge load average: ' + d)
        print(c)
        time.sleep(10)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
def stop(message):
    sent3 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'bye')
    print(sent3)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should solve the problem:

if you need to end the loop, you need to add "break" to the "stop" function

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('me_token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Please input server (example 
192.168.0.1)')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, cores)

def cores(message):
    global server
    server = (message.text)
    sent2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Input number of cores')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent2, botstarted)

def botstarted(message):
    global core
    global bye
    core = (message.text)
    cores = float(core)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Check started, if load average more then 
number of cores you get Warning message to stop enter /stop')
    while (True):
        b = os.popen('snmpwalk -v3 -l authNoPriv -u admin -a SHA -A "admin" ' + 
server + ' .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.1').read()
        d = (b[39:43])
        print(b[39:43])
        c = 56489
        if c > cores:
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Warning, huge load average: ' + d)
        print(c)
        time.sleep(1)

         @bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
         def stop(message):
             sent3 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'bye')
             print(sent3)
    
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76256417/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
bot.stop_polling()  but this = exit
```

Comment: It would be worth expanding on your answer with more details. Often code only answers, while they may be right, are downvoted.

Comment: any updates on this? my bot is running somewhere and I can't make an API request to it and stop it. The bot.infinity_polling() method is in an infinite try: finaly and can't exit